# jquery calendar: define custom icon

Tags: jquery-ui, calendar, icons, widget

when having a calendar widget assigned to a textbox, how can i trigger it from a separate icon? (i don't mean the internal showOn button feature).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can bind the separate icon with an event calling this function

```
$('#your-datepicker').datepicker('show');
```

look like

```
$('input#mybutton').click(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('show');
});
```